# Entity Framework: Save Object with foreign key without inserting new Object in Referenced Table

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two Tables which are created by using Entity Framework Core code first.
A `ApplicationUser` and his `ColorThemeSetting`. When a new User is created, a new ColorThemeSetting is also generated. But when I save, this error shows up:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ColorThemeSetting_AspNetUsers_SettingsOwnerId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "MyDb", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I think the EF tries to add a new User from the foreign key id. How can I prevent that?
Adding a new ColorThemeSetting:

```
//user and appUser are correctly initialized
var themeConfig = new ColorThemeSetting();
themeConfig.PrimaryColor = user.PrimaryColor ?? "";
themeConfig.SecondaryColor = user.SecondaryColor ?? "";
themeConfig.SettingsOwnerId = appUser.Id;
unitOfWork.ColorThemeSettings.Add(themeConfig);
```

The ColorThemeSetting Class:

```
public class ColorThemeSetting
{
    public string PrimaryColor { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryColor { get; set; }

    public string SettingsOwnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SettingsOwnerId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser SettingsOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If this code is executed for a new `appUser`, the `appUser.Id` is not correct at that point, you'd better set the navigation property, i.e. `themeConfig.SettingsOwner = appUser;`

Comment: At this time the  `appUser` is already in the db when a new one is created. The id is filled with the right id of the new user.

Comment: What @IvanStoev is correct. If the appUser is already saved in the db & if you are assigning that correct id to SettingsOwnerId you won't get FK violation. If your user is not saved then it would have temp value which will be replaced when saving the user. It would be better to use navigation property. Propagating temporary value like that requires more configuration.